¿Cómo puedo solucionar un problema con calendario realizado con PHP, para un sistema de gestión de máquinas?
Estoy realizando un calendario que lleva los mantenimientos de máquinas, la cosa que dependiendo de su vida útil ya sea 1, 2, 3 años y la frecuencia de mantenimiento 1 mes, 2 meses y asi sucesivamente se debe calcular las fechas de mantenimiento o sea yo agrego una fecha inicio, a partir de esa fecha inicio y con la vida útil y la frecuencia se generan los próximos mantenimientos. La cosa es, si logró insertar y la primera máquina no hay problema cumple con la frecuencia y la vida útil(años), el problema es al insertar más solo inserta una vez omitiendo la frecuencia y la vida útil. Yo tengo un break al final porque si no tengo ese break cada que recargo la página se me guarda nuevamente los datos.
   <?php
        require_once "config.php";
        
        // Máquinas activas
        $res = $mysqli->query("SELECT pk_maquinas, nombre_maquinas, fecha_ingreso FROM maquinas WHERE estado='Activo'");
        
        if (!$res) {
            die("Error en la consulta: " . $mysqli->error);
        }
        
        
        // Consulta de las máquinas y su información de mantenimiento
        $res_eventos = $mysqli->query("SELECT pk_mantPreventivo, fecha_ingreso, fecha_inicio, fk_maquinas, frecuencia_mant, dias_mant, estado_mant, vida_util 
        FROM calendario");
        
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_eventos)) {
            // Datos del evento inicial
            $pk_mantPreventivo = $row['pk_mantPreventivo'];
            $fecha_ingreso = $row['fecha_ingreso'];
            $fecha_inicio = $row['fecha_inicio'];
            $fk_maquinas = $row['fk_maquinas'];
            $frecuencia_mant = $row['frecuencia_mant'];
            $dias_mant = $row['dias_mant'];
            $estado_mant = $row['estado_mant'];
            $vida_util = $row['vida_util'];
        
            // Verificar que la vida útil sea válida
            if ($vida_util <= 0) {
                echo "Error: Vida útil no válida para la máquina $fk_maquinas.<br>";
                break; 
            }
        
            // Calcular la fecha límite según la vida útil (en años) desde la fecha de inicio
            $fecha_inicio_dt = new DateTime($fecha_inicio);
            $fecha_limite = clone $fecha_inicio_dt;
            $fecha_limite->modify("+$vida_util years");
        
            // Si ya existen eventos para esta máquina, ajustar el inicio al último evento generado
            if (isset($eventos_existentes[$fk_maquinas])) {
                $ultima_fecha_generada = new DateTime($eventos_existentes[$fk_maquinas]);
        
                // Si el último evento ya está más allá de la fecha límite, no generamos más eventos
                if ($ultima_fecha_generada >= $fecha_limite) {
                    echo "Ya se han generado suficientes eventos para la máquina $fk_maquinas.<br>";
                    continue; 
                }
        
                // Si el último evento es más reciente que la fecha de inicio, empezamos desde ahí
                $fecha_inicio_dt = max($fecha_inicio_dt, $ultima_fecha_generada);
            }
        
            // Definir el intervalo según la frecuencia de mantenimiento
            switch ($frecuencia_mant) {
                case 'mensual':
                    $frecuencia_intervalo = '1 month';
                    break;
                case '2meses':
                    $frecuencia_intervalo = '2 months';
                    break;
                case 'trimestral':
                    $frecuencia_intervalo = '3 months';
                    break;
                case 'semestral':
                    $frecuencia_intervalo = '6 months';
                    break;
                case 'anual':
                    $frecuencia_intervalo = '1 year';
                    break;
                default:
                    echo "Error: Frecuencia no válida para la máquina $fk_maquinas.<br>";
                    continue 2; // Pasamos a la siguiente máquina si la frecuencia es inválida
            }
        
            // Generar eventos según la frecuencia hasta alcanzar la vida útil
            $fecha_evento = clone $fecha_inicio_dt;
            $num_eventos = 0; // Contador para los eventos generados
            while ($fecha_evento < $fecha_limite) {
                $fecha_inicio_str = $fecha_evento->format('Y-m-d');
                $fecha_fin_dt = clone $fecha_evento;
                $fecha_fin_dt->modify("+$dias_mant days");
                $fecha_fin_str = $fecha_fin_dt->format('Y-m-d');
        
                // Verificar si la fecha actual supera la fecha límite
                if ($fecha_evento >= $fecha_limite) {
                    break;
                }
        
                // Verificar si ya existe un evento para esta máquina en esta fecha con estado 'Pendiente'
                $check_event_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM calendario WHERE fk_maquinas = ? AND fecha_inicio = ?";
                if ($stmt_check = $mysqli->prepare($check_event_sql)) {
                    $stmt_check->bind_param("ss", $fk_maquinas, $fecha_inicio_str);
                    $stmt_check->execute();
                    $stmt_check->bind_result($event_count);
                    $stmt_check->fetch();
                    $stmt_check->close();
        
                    // Si no existe un evento, insertar el nuevo evento
                    if ($event_count == 0) {
                        $insert_sql = "INSERT INTO calendario (fk_maquinas, frecuencia_mant, dias_mant, estado_mant, fecha_inicio, fecha_fin, vida_util) 
                                       VALUES (?, ?, ?, 'Pendiente', ?, ?, ?)";
                        if ($stmt_insert = $mysqli->prepare($insert_sql)) {
                            $stmt_insert->bind_param("ssssss", $fk_maquinas, $frecuencia_mant, $dias_mant, $fecha_inicio_str, $fecha_fin_str, $vida_util);
                            $stmt_insert->execute();
                            $stmt_insert->close();
                            $num_eventos++; // Incrementar el contador de eventos generados
                        } else {
                            echo "Error al preparar la consulta: " . $mysqli->error;
                        }
                        
                    } 
                   
                }
                // Incrementar la fecha del siguiente evento según la frecuencia
                $fecha_evento->modify($frecuencia_intervalo);
        
                // Si la fecha del próximo evento supera la vida útil, detener el ciclo
                if ($fecha_evento >= $fecha_limite) {
                    break; 
                }
            }
        
            break;
          
        }


Falta mostrar la salida de información, cuando el proceso falla. Debería al menos tirarte alguno de los errores.

Hice lo que me mencionaste, pero lo que pasa es que al poner el continue y borrar el break del final, procedo a guardar la máquina no tengo problemas guarda la cantidad que debe, pero si yo recargo la página guarda más datos, por ejemplo si yo tengo una vida útil (años) de 1 con una frecuencia mensual se deben agregar 12 eventos, esto lo hace bien lo que sucede es que si recargo la página se guardan 23 y así sucesivamente va aumentando, si yo pongo el break al final la primera en ingresar solo se guarda 12 veces ya la segunda y la demás solo una vez. :(

Entonces hay un problema de logica. Por que si ya registraste un mantenimiento reciente para una maquina, porque le vas a agregar otro? Al momento de tener su mantenimiento pendiente, no deberia volver a pasar por este proceso de asignacion nuevamente o me equivoco ?

Exacto no debería agregar más si ya la máquina fue ingresada, solamente se agrega una vez porque es basándonos en su vida útil, todavía no encuentro el error, pero estoy trabajando en ello.

No hay error, antes de entrar al proceso, debería haber un criterio que diga "esta maquina ya está registrada, no debe volver a entrar".

Por ejemplo deberías tener un IF, que considere la fecha de ingreso, y un rango mínimo de tiempo, en donde la maquina no entra al proceso. Entonces, digamos, si la maquina tiene menos de 3 meses sin revisar, que no se revise nuevamente.

Destacar que claramente, el break final no es la solución, asi que quítalo también.
Además de lo solicitado en el comentario, la salida de datos, yo creo que esta sección es incorrecta.
// Verificar que la vida útil sea válida
if ($vida_util <= 0) {
    echo "Error: Vida útil no válida para la máquina $fk_maquinas.<br>";
    break; 
}

Si la vida util, no es válida, no deberías detener el proceso, deberías continuar con la siguiente máquina, hasta que finalmente la validación final corte el proceso.
// Si la fecha del próximo evento supera la vida útil, detener el ciclo
if ($fecha_evento >= $fecha_limite) {
    break; 
}

Entonces, lo sugerido, es cambiar ese break; por un continue;.
// Verificar que la vida útil sea válida
if ($vida_util <= 0) {
    echo "Error: Vida útil no válida para la máquina $fk_maquinas.<br>";
    continue; //Cambiado el break por continue
}

